# How to not show the duplicate if it exists already?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I want to make an alphabet index for businesses, and struggling to eliminate the duplicate.
Like below:

```
T
  Toy Store 1
  Toy Store 2
  Toy Store 3
```

So I sliced the initial letter of the business and want to delete it if the letter is already shown like below:

```
T
  Toy Store 1
T // <- want to delete
  Toy Store 2
T // <- want to delete
  Toy Store 3
```

I tried using `new Set` but it does not work. I also tried using `indexOf` and filter method but didn't work either. Appreciate any help.

Component `ListItem`

```js
export default function CatListItem(props) {
  const {image,title,slicedInitial,onPress} = props;
    return (
      <View>
            <Text>
              {slicedInitial}
            </Text>
            <Text>
              {title}
            </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Screen:

```js
const renderList = () => {

//does not work
const indexedSlicedInitial=(item)=>{
  const slicedInital=item.title.slice(0,1)
  const index = [...new Set(slicedInital)]
  return index
}
//
    return (
      <View>
        {
          <Animated.FlatList
            data={data.list}
            key={"list"}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `list ${index}`}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <ListItem
                list
                title={item.title}
                slicedInitial={() => indexedSlicedInitial(item)}
                onPress={() => onProdDetail(item)}
              />
          />
    );
  };
```

Comment: I think you should sort alphabetically first with this for loop. Or alternatively, you group the data with the same index first and then render the new array (or object ) . are you vietnamese !?

Comment: Yes, I sort the data alphabetically already. Sorry I omitted it here since it's not directly related to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use *state* in screen component to store *prevIndex* so, that you can *compare* everytime you get newIndex.

If they are not same then only return new index otherwise return empty string. On ListItem component render text only if its not an empty string.

**Screen:**

```
// use state to store prev value
const [prevIndex, setPrevIndex] = useState('')

const renderList = () => {

const indexedSlicedInitial=(item)=>{
  const slicedInital=item.title.slice(0,1)
  
  // if they are different then only return new index
  if(prevIndex !== slicedInitial) {
    setPrevIndex(slicedInitial)
    return slicedInitial
  }

  // if slicedInitial same as prevIndex
  return "";
}

// no changes below
```

**Component ListItem:**

```
export default function CatListItem(props) {
  const {image,title,slicedInitial,onPress} = props;
  return (
    <View>
      // only output slicedInitial if not empty
      {slicedInitial ? <Text>
        {slicedInitial}
      </Text> : null}
      <Text>
        {title}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: This didn't work. It returns an error.

Comment: console log the result, where you get the error ?